# facebook wall into application

Tags: facebook, api

How can someone add the wall into a custom facebook application ?
example :
https://www.facebook.com/rihanna?sk=app_178091127385

Comment: If you're really asking a yes/no question, the answer is yes.  Perhaps you should rephrase it into a "how" question.

Comment: Obviously the question is not on the right track, it will have been helpfull if those minus votes had a comment for me to know what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the Graph API to  HTTP get `me/wall` of the owners wall you want to get the data for.